# static compile fails founding libs

Tags: compiling, shared-library, source

For some rescue task I need to compile extundelete and some other tools with shared libraries within the binary file.

I've been searching through `configure` and `make` options as well as AskUbuntu entries, etc. I've found the suggestion of using the `-strict` option, (single hyphen). Unfortunately I wasn't able to make it work.

I did the usual movements `apt source install extundelete`, `./configure`, `make`, off course also by adding '-static' to both ./configure and make. Nothing to do, don't work.

Finally I got some hint by putting '-static' in the LDFLAGS environment variable. Now at least I've got a specific error message!

```
./configure LDFLAGS=-static

Configuring extundelete 0.2.4
configure: error: Can't find ext2fs library
```

All the suggestions I found point to the lack of e2fslibs-dev and/or libext2fs-dev packages. After install this packages the error message remains the same. `Can't find ext2fs library`

Just in case I checked the packages contents and in effect there is the ext2fs library, or so it would seem.

```
dpkg -L libext2fs-dev | grep ext2fs
/usr/include/ext2fs
/usr/include/ext2fs/bitops.h
/usr/include/ext2fs/ext2_err.h
/usr/include/ext2fs/ext2_ext_attr.h
/usr/include/ext2fs/ext2_fs.h
/usr/include/ext2fs/ext2_io.h
/usr/include/ext2fs/ext2_types.h
/usr/include/ext2fs/ext2fs.h
/usr/include/ext2fs/ext3_extents.h
/usr/include/ext2fs/qcow2.h
/usr/include/ext2fs/tdb.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ext2fs.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.so
/usr/share/doc/libext2fs-dev
```

At this point my hacking resources are exhausted. Any help will be very welcome. Tanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `config.log` file, you will likely see that although the error message is `Can't find ext2fs library`, the actual error is related to undefined references *within* `libext2fs.a`

```
configure:5298: checking for ext2fs_bmap in -lext2fs
configure:5323: gcc -o conftest   -static conftest.c -lext2fs   >&5
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.a(alloc_stats.o): In function `ext2fs_inode_alloc_stats2':
(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `com_err'
```

I was able to get it to configure and build using

```
./configure CFLAGS=-pthread LDFLAGS='-pthread -static' LIBS=-lcom_err
make
```

i.e.

```
$ file -b ./src/extundelete
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=a03a7d251e42c8a9182b062841f81e5d1cccc7c7, with debug_info, not stripped
```

**Note that I did not try to actually run it**.

If you omit the `-pthread` options, it will likely give other errors about unresolved semaphore prototypes `sem_wait` etc. **I have no idea if this is the "right" resolution**.

Comment: Thanks you @steeldriver. Your suggests make things to work. Unfortunately a seg fault comes when i try to use the binary I get. Seems to be lib version issue.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/178440/accidental-deletion-of-home?answertab=active#tab-top